# How to show that an abelian group is a right $R$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

If I want to show that an abelian group $M$ is a right $R$-module, I need to produce a ring homomorphism $\psi: R \to End_{Ab}(M)$.

**However, do I need $\psi(rs)=\psi(r) \circ \psi(s)$ or do I need $\psi(rs)=\psi(s) \circ \psi(r)$?**

Comment: Depends: do your endomorphisms operate on the left or on the right? Does $f\circ g$ mean “do $g$ first, then do $f$”, or does it mean “do $f$ first, then do $g$”?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I usually have $f\circ g$ to mean do $g$ first, then do $f$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin If we have $rs$ acting on $m$ on the right, then we write $m \cdot rs$. So, formally this would pertain to $\psi(s) \circ \psi(r)$?

Comment: So then, since you need $m(rs) = (mr)s$, that means that you need $\psi(rs) = \psi(s)\circ\psi(r)$.